# A Good Way to Deal with DTD being Blacklisted by w3.org

Tags: php, xslt, w3c, dtd

We've used php to build up an interface that the client can upload svg graphic, then click the button to do an XSLT transform.

The interface and underlying XSLT worked perfectly fine previously, until recently, the xslt process will always fail and return error like: could not find www.w3.org or sth (Cannot remember quite exactly).

Our client uses Adobe Illustrator to create SVG graphics, and then use our tool to do the transform, and the SVG graphics that directly come out of Adobe Illustrator has the following three lines on the top of every SVG file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 15.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00       
  Build0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG   
 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

We did some research and we came to conclustion that w3.org is blacklisting our client's server (Windows Server 2003). The normal workaround is to do a resolver. Since the client will only give us 1 hour or so to do the remote control on their stuff, so I am thinking if there is a simpler way to handle this issue.

One proposed way is we could place a flatfile.dtd on client server, so every incoming SVG file can reference that, and we use the php to manipulate the SVG file, scan the file until it finds the `"<!DOCTYPE.."` string, then replace the whole string with another `"<!DOCTYPE.."` in which the url is now pointing the local flatfile.dtd, save the file and then begin the XSLT process. Then after the translation, we do the reverse process, which is to reset the dtd url from our local dtd to the default w3.org one.

I will try do this tomorrow, and our demo is on Friday. So I am just seeking some advice here if this way is realisitic and has it any risks? Or, could any experts give some better alternatives to deal with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the DTD to load? you might just skip that..

Comment: What are you using for XSLT processing? I would suspect that a catalog is the correct answer but not all tools support them.

Comment: W3C isn't blacklisting you specifically - it's rejecting all requests for these commonly-used DTDs. They simply can't cope with the traffic. They should have thought of this about ten years ago, but they just assumed that there would be so much caching in the web that it wouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure that your approach of hacking a redirection to a local copy is better than doing it "properly" with an entity resolver.

Comment: @Wrikken - XSLT processing always requires the DTD to be read, even if you're not validating. It might contain entity definitions or defaulted attribute values or definitions of ID attributes.

Comment: @Nic: I am using Saxon to do that. Do you think doing a redirect to a local copy will help?

Comment: @Robert. Saxon can use a catalog based resolver. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear but I think you're saying you only need a temporary fix for the purposes of a demo? If so, why not add an entry to the server's host file that maps www.w3.org to 127.0.0.1 (localhost) or to the ip of a server that you control? Then you can populate the path of this server with the appropriate dtd file. After the demo, don't forget to remove the host entry so everything is back as it was.

The nice thing about this is that you don't have to manipulate the DOCTYPE string in your code since the existing url will resolve to a server that you control.

This solution assumes that you don't have to dereference any other resources at www.w3.org besides this dtd. You should be able to test this on any server that runs your demo though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already tested on my localhost server, and it worked. But I wonder where the host file of Windows Server 2003 is and modify the host file there will have the same effect as my local server?

Comment: @Robert: I believe hosts is in %SytemRoot% in Windows. The [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Can you pre-process the SVG to remove the DOCTYPE declaration entirely? (Can you treat the SVG as well-formed instead of valid or do you need to validate the SVG too?)

I've had issues when creating PDF's from XSL-FO using SVG's. If the SVG's had a DOCTYPE declaration, the processor would resolve the declaration. I didn't get any errors, as it was able to resolve the DOCTYPE, but it was ***SLOW***. Stripping the DOCTYPE at run-time improved the speed greatly.

Comment: I mean remove the DOCTYPE declaration from the SVG itself. Unless you need to validate the SVG, you don't need it.